# findElement by.xpath not working for Html5 section tag?

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

findElement by xpath is not working for section tags. I tried several times xpath is also not a dynamic one it is a static one but still I get this message

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: `{"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[2]/section/div/div/div/div/div/form/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/input"}`
>   Command duration or timeout: 6.66 seconds"

I also searched several forms regarding this problem many said to use latest selenium standlone jar file. I am using only the latest version "selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar"

Relevant HTML :

```
<div id="uploading-url">
   <p class="reduce-space"><img alt="web_image" src="/images/content/duelr/web.png"></p>
   <input placeholder="Enter URLs to upload from web" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Show us relevant HTML

Comment: @olyv The relevant HTML is <div id="uploading-url">
                            <p class="reduce-space"><img alt="web_image" src="/images/content/duelr/web.png"></p>
                            <input placeholder="Enter URLs to upload from web" type="text"></div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following xpath to get element for `input` tag:

```
//div[@id='uploading-url']//input
```